Git Alias - Create multiple merge request from one source branch to multiple target branches
I'm trying to create a git alias to create three merge request (master, release, develop) from the current working branch. Somehow it doesn't recognize the -o merge_request.target=* on the seconde and third git push.
Currently I've got the following Git alias
[alias]
    mr-master = "!git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=master origin HEAD"
    mr-release = "!git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=release origin HEAD"
    mr-develop = "!git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=develop -o merge_request.remove_source_branch origin HEAD"

    hotfix = !git mr-master && git mr-release && git mr-develop

Running it by git hotfix will only create the first merge request but not the second or third, those return Everything up-to-date
Am I overlooking something or isn't this possible at all?
I'm running Git 2.44.0 locally on windows and using Gitlab 16.6.7-ee.

Why do you ned your bn alias? Just git push origin HEAD to push your current branch.

What's your branching strategy, and what's the reason you wish to create all 3 MRs? If you're using a branching strategy like Git Flow, there may be a better way to achieve your desired outcome, than by using those 3 MRs.

"Everything up-to-date" is something returned by git push. So it looks like after the first push you can't push the same identical thing again for the second and third try. Maybe you can change either the branch name and push again (and delete the branch all 3 times), or change the tip commit ID and force push it. I'd probably lean towards the first choice- 3 different branch names, one per MR, and delete the branch each time. If you go with the same branch name for all 3 MRs, you must complete them in the proper order, or else you might accidentally delete it before the others complete.
